# How to create a UITableView full of UITableViewCells each with a UISwitch?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I'm making a phonebook.

I'm trying to create a UITableView that has a prototype cell in it that contains a UISwitch which describes if a particular contact is public or private.

How can I create this such that the UISwitch keeps its toggle status even during scroll? `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is giving me a lot of problems in that it doesn't save the togglestate of the UISwitches.

Though I love the memory savings, toggling the switches within cellForRowAtIndexPath (according to a contact's privacy boolean value) is not working to always display the public/private status of a contact.

See screenshot below of what I'm trying to build:

[image]

EDIT: Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AHBContact *thisContact = nil;

    AHBBrowseContactCell *cell  =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BROWSECELL"];

    // from  contacts list
    thisContact = [self.contacts[indexPath.section] allValues][0][indexPath.row];

    cell.customPublicSwitch.onTintColor = [AHBUtilities greenColor];
    cell.customPublicSwitch.onText= @"Public";
    cell.customPublicSwitch.offText=@"Private";

    if(thisContact.privacy){
        NSLog(@"public %@",thisContact.fullName);
       cell.customPublicSwitch.on = YES;

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"private %@", thisContact.fullName);

       cell.customPublicSwitch.on = NO;

    }

    cell.labelName.text = thisContact.fullName;
    cell.labelName.font = [AHBUtilities regularFontWithSize:cell.labelName.font.pointSize];
    cell.imageViewIcon.image = [AHBIcons phoneIconForCategory:thisContact.category];

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.55];

    return cell;
}
```

SECOND EDIT: Here's my "togglePublic" method that runs on "valueChanged" of the switch

```
    -(IBAction)togglePublic:(UIControl *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        DCRoundSwitch *switch1 = (DCRoundSwitch *)button;
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)switch1.superview;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForCell: cell.superview];

        if ( indexPath == nil ){

            return;

        }

        AHBContact *contact = [self.contacts[indexPath.section] allValues][0][indexPath.row];

        contact.privacy = !contact.privacy;

        NSLog(@"Public switch toggled for: %@", contact.firstName);

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

[[AHBContactsController sharedController] updateContact:contact completion:^(id result) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];


           NSLog (@"Public/Private updated%@",result);


       } failure:^(NSError *error) {

           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

           UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sync Problem"
                                                             message:@"Could save changes. Please try again."
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [message show];



       }];

    }
```

Comment: Settings the switch's state in `cellForRow...` is a valid approach. If it's not working then you are doing something wrong. Post your `cellForRow...` method.

Comment: @rmaddy just added the edit -- let me know what you think!

Comment: The code appears correct. Perhaps the issue is with handling the switch's value being changed. Do you have code that responds to the switch being changed by the user and then updating the proper `AHBContact` record with the new value?

Comment: @rmaddy added another edit to show my toggle method which runs on "valueChanged" of the switch

Comment: Have you verified that the `togglePublic:withEvent:` method is actually called when a switch is toggled by the user? If it is, is it updating the same data objects used by the table view's data source?

Comment: It definitely does run when the switch is toggled...may not be updating the datasource -- will verify!

Comment: @rmaddy Fixed this a few hours ago, no effect. It seems the switches are still just being reused

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it in the delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDsiplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UISwitch *switch = cell.yourCellSwitch;
    switch.on = yourSwitchVariable;
}
```

Comment: just tried this, didn't work when I scroll around. Basically, the switch toggles but then is that switch/cell is randomly reused by other cells (which now show incorrect public/private information as a result)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the switch that you are creating in **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** is the problem. Try doing like this. Create a custom cell with UILabel and a UISwitch. Make these IBOutlets and a property of the custom cell and connect them. Now in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method use the custom cell instead of your default cell. As the cell are being reused and this method gets called each time when a cell becomes visible on the screen I guess there occurs an inconsistency as you are creating UISwitch each time and then assigning its state

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

        YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (!cell)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                    cell =  (YourCustomCell *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

       // from  contacts list
            thisContact = [self.contacts[indexPath.section] allValues][0][indexPath.row];
    if(thisContact.privacy){
            NSLog(@"public %@",thisContact.fullName);
           cell.customPublicSwitch.on = YES;

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"private %@", thisContact.fullName);

           cell.customPublicSwitch.on = NO;

        }

        cell.labelName.text = thisContact.fullName;
        cell.labelName.font = [AHBUtilities regularFontWithSize:cell.labelName.font.pointSize];
        cell.imageViewIcon.image = [AHBIcons phoneIconForCategory:thisContact.category];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.55];
     return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just tried this, doesn't seem to work for me -- same issue even when I remove "AHBBrowseContactCell *cell = (AHBBrowseContactCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
" entirely. It's not even dequeueing and the the cells are still getting messed up (but this time they're just getting reset to their default state only)! How is this possible?? Also, I'm noticing that setting my UISwitch to on (setOn) triggers "valueChanged" and fires an update...could this be an issue?

Comment: Can you paste your current code. I cant tell you the exact reason without looking the code